# Java Scanner: InputMismatchException - can't read CSV file with multiple lines using next() and hasNext() methods:

Tags: java

I have a `test.txt` file with these contents:

```
A,B,1,0.5
C,D,2,1.5
```

I have this code that reads its contents and prints to console:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(Paths.get("test.txt"));
            input.useDelimiter("\\,");
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                System.out.printf("%s %s %d %f",
                        input.next(),
                        input.next(),
                        input.nextInt(),
                        input.nextDouble());
                input.next();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it gives an `InputMismatchException` error.

While if the file contains just

```
A,B,1,0.5
```

it works fine. I suspected that it's because the `nextDouble()` leaves a trailing new line character and tried adding `input.next()`, however the error is still there.

**EDIT**:

I know of the `String line = scanner.nextLine()` and `String[] data = line.split(",")` approach. However I want to understand what is wrong here. I don't want to use a library for this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a single Scanner for the whole thing. Divide and conquer: instead, use one Scanner to read each line of the file, and a second line Scanner based on each line (or `String#split(...)`) to parse each line.

```
    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(Paths.get("test.txt"));
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            // or create a Scanner based on the line here and close when done

            // handle tokens here
            
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
    }
```

Or better still, use a CSV parsing library.

Answer (score 0):

To also accept a line break as a delimiter, use the pattern `,|\R`.

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get("test.txt")) {
    input.useDelimiter(",|\\R");
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s %d %f%n", input.next(), input.next(), input.nextInt(), input.nextDouble());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, parse the last part of the line separately.

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get("test.txt")) {
    input.useDelimiter(",");
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s %d %f%n", input.next(), input.next(), input.nextInt(),
                Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine().substring(1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error. And I'd like to do it wuthout complex regex

Comment: Sorry my bad. It worked when I removed `input.next`

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same while keeping a comma as a delimeter?

Comment: @parsecer Why can't you use regex?

Comment: I want to understand how to use pure `Scanner` solution. Like, what's going on inside `Scanner` here and which character causes the error

Comment: @parsecer The presence of the line break at the end of each line causes the error, as the last token to be matched on the first line is "0.5\nC", which cannot be parsed as a `Double`. This is why it is necessary to also use the line break as a delimiter, unless you want to add commas to the end of all the lines. This is completely `Scanner`-based, as it uses regular expressions internally anyway.